# Why is $P(|x|\ge\varepsilon) = P(x^2\ge \varepsilon^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the Chebyshev inequality. The step I cannot really follow is the identity: $P(|x-\mu|\ge\varepsilon) = P((x-\mu)^2 \ge \varepsilon^2)$. Can anyone explain the intuition behind this or give some other form of insight? That would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Because $\{|x-\mu|\geq \varepsilon \}=\{(x-\mu)^2\geq \varepsilon ^2\}$.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the probability.

Comment: If $a\ge 0$ then $b\ge c \implies ab\ge ac$.

Comment: Should assume $\varepsilon >0$ though for the equality to hold

Comment: Thank you all, that was really helpful. Now I understand it!

Answer (score 2):

$\{x\mid |x-\mu| \ge \varepsilon\}= \{x\mid (x-\mu)^2 \ge \varepsilon^2\}$ so have the measure of the same set as the probability.

If $|a| \ge b >0$ then $a^2 = a\cdot a = |a|\cdot |a| \ge b \cdot b=b^2$ by standard arithmetic facts about the order on $\Bbb R$ and the reverse follows by taking square roots and realising that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ etc.
Apply to $a=x-\mu$ and $b=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you! That did help clarify it!

Answer (score 2):

If $\varepsilon>0$, the probabilities are the same because these sets are the same:

$$\{x:|x-\mu|\geq \varepsilon\}=\{x:(x-\mu)^2\geq \varepsilon^2\}.$$

To see LHS implies RHS, recall the squaring function $f:z\rightarrow z^2$ is increasing for $z\geq 0$  so preserves inequalities when applied to both sides (where both sides are nonnegative).

Likewise RHS implies LHS because the square root function $f:z\rightarrow \sqrt z$ is increasing for $z\geq 0$  so preserves inequalities when applied to both sides (where both sides are nonnegative).

Comment: Thank you, too! In sum, the different ways to explain it really helped! :)